# MappingJackson2JsonView Bean breaks after adding ViewResolverRegistry to SpringWebConfig

Tags: java, spring, jackson

**RESOLVED** - see answer.

I've looked through many similar questions and don't see a similar case right off.  Certainly this isn't a unique situation and I'm just missing it?

***Update*** [A Spring example I found shows a priority property](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/configure-multiple-view-resolvers-priority-in-spring-mvc/) that may help here, but I have only found the XML example.  Question expanded below.

**Problem Summary**

Two view resolvers appear to be conflicting in my SpringWebMVC application.

**Problem Details**

I'm work on a web app using Spring 4.0.3-RELEASE and have recently added Jackson to support returning Json from calls to a specific controller.  This was working until I added an @Override to my SpringWebConfig for configureViewResolvers.  Now my calls to my controller which was serving Json just return the template name which should call the Jackson mapper bean.

**The big question**

How can I make these two coexist? I have found that I can call:

```
registry.order(int)
```

and set it to 9 just to make sure it was last, but it still intercepted the jsonTemplate response from the controller.  I don't see a way to set an order for the MappingJackson2JsonView bean.   @Bean(order=0), for example, is invalid.

**Things Tried**

Redacting the ViewResolverRegistry, as expected, produces an error when trying to get mapped jsp views.

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 'someView' in servlet with name 'spring-mvc-dispatcher'
```

As noted in the question statement above, I've tried setting the order on the registry for the ViewResolverRegistry, but this did not help.

I also have tried adding the following to the MappingJackson2JsonView instance, view:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("order", 1);
view.setAttributes(props);
```

But as before, this doesn't prevent the ViewResolverRegistry from intercepting "jsonTemplate" before the Jackson mapper can process it.

I also have changed the load order of the configs in the AppInitializer, the code below has been updated to reflect the new load order, but this also did not help.

Reading through the Spring documentation a bit more, it appears that adding a ContentNegotiationConfigurer is going to be what I need to resolve this and I'm presently looking at how to get this to work in a way that preserves auto mapping the Model returned to the jsonTemplate view.  Exapmles I've seen so far use a jsp as a view with specific properties called out, which defeats the purpose of using a Json Mapper.

**Configuration**

I have multiple config classes defined in my package com.mytest.config.

*AppInitializer.java* handles adding the *config classes to the context.
    package com.mytest.config;

```
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

public class AppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AppInitializer.class);

@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {

    try {
AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        ctx.register(JSONConfiguration.class);
        ctx.register(SpringWebConfig.class);


        ctx.setServletContext(container);
        container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(ctx));
        container.addListener(new RequestContextListener());

        logger.info("Created AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext");

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = container.addServlet("spring-mvc-dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");

        logger.info("DispatcherServlet added to AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext");

} catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
        }

    }

}
```

*SpringWebConfig.java* is where I register the majority of my beans.

```
package com.mytest.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.InterceptorRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewResolverRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.mytest.controller","com.mytest.bean","com.mytest.model"})

@PropertySource(value={"classpath:application.properties"})
public class SpringWebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private Environment env;

private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SpringWebConfig.class);

    // bunches of beans such as JdbcTemplate, DataSource... omitted for simplicity


    @Override // apparent problem location -- needed for jsp resolving
    public void configureViewResolvers(final ViewResolverRegistry registry) {       
        registry.jsp("/WEB-INF/views/html/",".jsp");
    }


    @Override 
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
        logger.info("DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer enabled");
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry){      
        registry.addInterceptor(new com.honda.hrao.rid.config.RequestInterceptor());
        logger.info("RequestInterceptor added to InterceptorRegistry");
    }
}
```

*JSONConfiguration.java* is a controller I set up just for JSON.

```
package com.mytest.config;

import java.util.Properties;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.View;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJackson2JsonView;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.mytest.controller"})
@EnableWebMvc

public class JSONConfiguration {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JSONConfiguration.class);

      @Bean  // needed for JSON conversion of bean responses
        public View jsonTemplate() {
          logger.info("Registered MappingJackson2JsonView");
            MappingJackson2JsonView view = new MappingJackson2JsonView();
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put("order", 1);
            view.setAttributes(props);
            view.setPrettyPrint(true);
            return view;
        }

        @Bean
        public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
            logger.info("Starting ViewResolver bean");
            return new BeanNameViewResolver();
        }

}
```

**Implementation**

In my Controller, the following method should return JSON.

```
@Autowired
AppConstants appConstants;

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "getAppConstants")
    public String getAppConstants(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("AppConstants",appConstants);
        if(appConstants==null) {
            Logger.error("appConstants not autowired!!!");
            return null;
        }
        return "jsonTemplate";
    }
```

As mentioned above in Things Tried, this works fine if I remove the ViewResolverRegistry bean from the SpringWebConfig and if I leave the bean in place, the above controller method returns

```
404, /WEB-INF/views/html/jsonTemplate.jsp 
The requested resource is not available.
```

-- which I understand.  That's what the view resolver should do.  How do I make my JSON calls bypass this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there were only a couple of things missing.  The first was to add the following annotation to the bean declaration for the mapper:

```
@Primary
```

So now, the bean setup looks like this.

```
  @Bean  // needed for JSON conversion of bean responses
  @Primary
    public View jsonTemplate() {
      logger.info("Registered MappingJackson2JsonView");
        MappingJackson2JsonView view = new MappingJackson2JsonView();
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("order", 1);
        view.setAttributes(props);
        view.setPrettyPrint(true);          
        return view;
    }
```

The second was to use a ContentNegotiationConfigurer.  In my SpringWebConfig, I added the following:

```
public void configurationContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer
            .ignoreUnknownPathExtensions(false)
        .defaultContentType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML);
    }
```

and changed my configureViewResolvers function as follows:

```
@Override // needed for jsp resolving
    public void configureViewResolvers(final ViewResolverRegistry registry) {    
        MappingJackson2JsonView view = new MappingJackson2JsonView();
        view.setPrettyPrint(true);      
        registry.enableContentNegotiation(view);        
        registry.jsp("/WEB-INF/views/html/",".jsp");
    }
```

One clue was found in [this example](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?source_dir=availability-master/src/main/java/com/integralblue/availability/config/WebMvcConfig.java#).  The rest came from the Spring documentation.